# Return del store de redux me devuelve un obejeto y no un array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

es mi segundo problema más grande creando una app en donde consumo una API ( la de rick and morty )

En este caso en concreto, lo que hice básicamente, fue pasar información especifica de un personaje por medio de su id, y luego la guardo en una variable utilizando el hook useState, luego, si el usuario si quiere agregar el personaje a favoritos, se enviara la información por medio de un dispatch, y se guardara en el store, luego lo que hago es, obtener esa información en un componente diferente utilizando useSelector.

Todo bien hasta allí, hasta que intento mapear la información, lo que sucede es que cuando pido la información, me devuelve un objeto, y dentro del objeto esta el array, lo que significa que si intento mapear la información con .map(), no me dejara, porque es un objeto y no un array, lo cual se me hace extraño y no encuentro como solucionarlo

Probando con console.log, veo que en mi reducer, si me devuelve un array, pero de alguna manera, usando useSelector, mete el array dentro de un objeto, alguien que me ayude a solucionar el error?

Pasando la información a redux, en la función Modal

```
import React, {
 useState,
 useEffect,
 useRef,
 useMemo,
 useCallback
} from "react";

import "./Cards.css";

import loading from "../Images/loading.png";
import { FaCircle } from "react-icons/fa";
import { BiMessageSquareAdd } from "react-icons/bi";
import SearchBar from "../components/Search";
import Favorites from "../components/Favorites";

import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { FAVORITES } from "../constants/Types";

const Cards = ({ styles }) => {
 // Variables

 const [Data, setData] = useState([]);
 const [singleCharacter, setSingleCharacter] = useState({});
 const [number, setNumber] = useState(1);
 const [Loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

 const searchInput = useRef(null);
 const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

 const [modal, setModal] = useState();

 const dispatch = useDispatch();

 // Search Bar

 const handleSearch = useCallback(() => {
   setSearch(searchInput.current.value);
 }, []);

 const filteredCharacters = useMemo(
   () =>
     Data.filter(user => {
       return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase());
     }),
   [Data, search]
 );

 // Fetching rick and morty's api

 const url = `https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=${number}`;

 const handleData = () => {
   setNumber(number + 1);
   setLoading(!Loading);
 };

 const fetching = async () => {
   try {
     const res = await fetch(url);
     const data = await res.json();
     setLoading(!Loading);
     setData(Data.concat(data.results));
   } catch (error) {
     console.log(error);
   }
 };

 useEffect(() => {
   fetching();
 }, [number]);

 // Passing The Fucking Data Homie

 const passingData = (character, id) => {
   setSingleCharacter(character);

   // document.getElementById("id").style.display = "none";

   setModal(true);
 };

 // Showing or Not Showing Modal

 const Modal = () => {
   dispatch({ type: FAVORITES, payload: singleCharacter });

   setModal(false);
 };

 const NoModal = () => {
   setModal(false);
   setSingleCharacter({});
 };

 if (Loading) {
   return (
     <div className={styles ? "Loading-black" : "Loading"}>
       <img src={loading} alt="" />
     </div>
   );
 } else {
   return (
     <>
       {/* Modal Window */}

       <div className={modal ? "Modal" : "No-Modal"}>
         <div className={modal ? "Modal-container" : "No-Modal-container"}>
           <h2>
             Do You Want To Add <br /> {singleCharacter.name} To Favorites ?
           </h2>
           <div>
             <span onClick={Modal}>Yes</span>
             <span onClick={NoModal}>Nop</span>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div className={styles ? "Cards-container_black" : "Cards-container"}>
         {/* Favorites */}
         <Favorites />
         {/*  */}

         {/* Search Bar */}

         <SearchBar
           styles={styles}
           search={search}
           searchInput={searchInput}
           handleSearch={handleSearch}
         />

         {filteredCharacters.map(character => {
           const {
             id,
             name,
             status,
             species,
             gender,
             origin,
             image
           } = character;
           return (
             <div className="Cards-container_character" key={id}>
               <div
                 className="Character-img"
                 style={{
                   background: `url(${image})`,
                   backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                   backgroundSize: "cover",
                   maxWidth: "100%",
                   height: "auto"
                 }}
               ></div>
               <div
                 className={styles ? "Character-inf_black" : "Character-inf"}
               >
                 <h2 className="Character-inf_title">{name}</h2>
                 {status === "Alive" ? (
                   <p className="Character-inf_text">
                     {" "}
                     <FaCircle className="Status-alive" /> {status} - {species}{" "}
                   </p>
                 ) : (
                   <p className="Character-inf_text">
                     {" "}
                     <FaCircle className="Status-dead" /> {status} - {species}{" "}
                   </p>
                 )}

                 <p className="Character-inf_text2">{gender}</p>
                 <h2 className="Character-inf_title">Origin</h2>
                 <p className="Character-inf_text2">{origin.name}</p>
                 <p
                   onClick={() => passingData(character, id)}
                   className="Character-inf_text3"
                   id="id"
                 >
                   <BiMessageSquareAdd /> Add To Fav
                 </p>
               </div>
             </div>
           );
         })}
         <div className="More">
           <button onClick={handleData} className="More-button">
             More Data
           </button>
         </div>
       </div>
     </>
   );
 }
};

export default Cards;
```

Mi reducer

```
import { FAVORITES } from "../constants/Types";

const Data = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FAVORITES:
      console.log(state);
      return [...state, action.payload];

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default Data;
```

Obteniendo la información del reducer

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import "./Favorites.css";

import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const Favorites = () => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  const favorites = useSelector(state => state);

  console.log(favorites);

  const handleToggle = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  };

  return (
    //   Favorites
    <>
      <div className={toggle ? "Favorites-toggle" : "Favorites"}>
        <h2 onClick={handleToggle}>Favorites </h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        {/* {favorites.map(favorite => {
          const { id, name, status, species, gender, origin, image } = favorite;
          return (
            <div key={id}>
              <img src={image} alt="" />
              <h2>{name}</h2>
            </div>
          );
        })} */}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Favorites;
```

Lugar De Condiguración Del Store (ignoren por favor lo de redux-thunk, me equivoque instalandolo ya que en realidad no lo utilizaría)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";
import { reducers } from "./reducers";

import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";

const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Configuración reducer

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

import Reducer from "./Reducer";

export const reducers = combineReducers({ Reducer });
```

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código de `configureStore` en store.js?, quiero saber cómo esta configurado el `top-level state object`, saludos

Comment: Amigo ya lo puse en el post, lo actualize, allí esta !

Comment: Ya lo logre resolver, como estaba usando la función de combineReducers que me retorna un objeto, no puedo mapear en el, así que en mi store, no hice referencia a mis multiples reducers porque solo necesitare uno, e hice mi único reducer la referencia para crear la store, ahora sí me retorna un objeto !

Comment: Puedes publicar tu propia respuesta, saludos